# Is there an easy way to enter/edit code in Rstudio? Avoiding repetition?

Tags: r

So I have the following code, as you can see this command will not run in R because it is missing a comma after each word and furthermore since these are characters I would need to enter a `"` before and after each word. Rather than going to each word and typing a `"` before and after and then a `comma` - is there an easy way to do this? I couldn't find a command that makes this easier from Rstudio's [site](https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/200711853-Keyboard-Shortcuts) - or I don't understand which one I need to use.

```
base_pckgs <- c(
    base
    compiler
    datasets
    graphics
    grDevices
    grid
    methods
    parallel
    splines
    stats
    stats4
    tcltk
    tools
    translations

)
```

Desired Output (without actually typing in a `"` and `,` in each row.

Comment: Maybe using `find+replace` after having selected the text you want to modify? This method also allows you to use `regex`.

Comment: Is this a generic question for problems of this type, or is your specific aim to generate a vector of base package names? If the latter, there are ways to do that.

Answer (score 2):

Check out the `datapasta` add-in on CRAN or at https://github.com/MilesMcBain/datapasta. It adds some handy tools to RStudio's Addins menu. One, for instance, will let you paste your long list of packages as a vector:

`c("base", "compiler", "datasets", "graphics", "grDevices", "grid", "methods", "parallel", "splines", "stats", "stats4", "tcltk", "tools", "translations")`

Answer (score 1):

If you are wanting to load a list of libraries, then you could put the list into `read.table`, then turn it into a list, then use `lapply` to load all libraries.

```
read.table(text = "
  base
  compiler
  datasets
  graphics
  grDevices
  grid
  methods
  parallel
  splines
  stats
  stats4
  tcltk
  tools
  translations
  ") %>% 
  .[,1] %>% 
  lapply(., require, character.only = TRUE)
```

Or if you are wanting a quick way to add quotes and commas to create a vector, then you can use a combination of `scan` and `dput`.

```
dput(scan(text = "
  base
  compiler
  datasets
  graphics
  grDevices
  grid
  methods
  parallel
  splines
  stats
  stats4
  tcltk
  tools
  translations
  ", what=""))

c("base", "compiler", "datasets", "graphics", "grDevices", "grid", 
"methods", "parallel", "splines", "stats", "stats4", "tcltk", 
"tools", "translations")
```

This could also be piped into `lapply` too:

```
dput(scan(text = "
  base
  compiler
  datasets
  graphics
  grDevices
  grid
  methods
  parallel
  splines
  stats
  stats4
  tcltk
  tools
  translations
  ", what="")) %>% 
  lapply(., require, character.only = TRUE)
```